# Reactnative IOS pushotification/PushNotificationIOS onNotification does not called directly when notification received

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, notifications, push-notification-ios

I used reactnative  PushNotification/PushNotificationIOS modules , My issue is when notification received on foreground to my device IOS ,the function onNotification: function(notification) {}  does not called directly is called by click only .
I want to fetch data notification paylaod sent via pububnub console directly without any user interaction ,this function is working fine in android  but ios not all.
the console does not show anything can help me to solve this issue and thanks.

This the function and imports module:

```js
import PushNotification from "react-native-push-notification";
import PushNotificationIOS from "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios";

onNotification: function(notification) {
if (Platform.OS=='ios')
{

  console.log('notif',notification)

 
notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);

},
 
    onAction: function (notification) {
  
    },
   
    onRegistrationError: function(err) {
  
    },
  permissions: {
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    },
   popInitialNotification: true,
    requestPermissions: true,
    senderID: FIREBASE_SENDER_ID,
})
}
```

and this the object pubnub to send :

```json
{"pn_apns":{
      "aps":{
        "alert": {
            "body": "Course disponible",
            "title": "My course"
        },
        "sound": "beep.wav",
            
"data": { "reference": "ND1004332", "startstation": ""  }
          },


      "pn_push":[
         {
            "push_type":"alert",
            "auth_method":"token",
            "targets":[
               {
                  "environment":"development",
                  "topic":"com.test.fr"
               }
            ],
            "version":"v2"
         }
      ]

}
      
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import {Platform} from 'react-native';
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';
import PushNotificationIOS from "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios"; 
if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
// Must be outside of any component LifeCycle (such as `componentDidMount`).
PushNotification.configure({
    onNotification: function (notification) {
        console.log("NOTIFICATION:", notification);
        const { foreground, userInteraction, title, message } = notification;
        if (foreground && (title || message) && !userInteraction) PushNotification.localNotification(notification);
        notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
    },

    permissions: {
        // alert: true,
        // badge: true,
        sound: true
      },
});
}
```